# How to get full path in terminal and what PS1 cmd to use in bashrc

Tags: linux, bashrc

Every time I change the directory I get only current directory name but I want full path what cmd should I use in my .bashrc file ?

currently, i am trying as follows

```
export PS1="\W >"
```

But it does not work

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are using uppercase `W` and not lowercase `w`.

Here is a good page for an intro to customizing the shell prompt.
https://linuxhint.com/bash-ps1-customization/